# What does this MiniTest::Unit::TestCase warning mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

My tests were running without problems, when suddenly the following warning appeared:

```
MiniTest::Unit::TestCase is now Minitest::Test
```

This was reported in the following libs:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit/testcase.rb:8:in `<module:Unit>'
gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/test_case.rb:12:in `<module:ActiveSupport>'
gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/descendants_tracker.rb:34:in `inherited'
```

I have no idea what prompted these warnings to appear. Does anybody know what I can do to eliminate the warnings?

The test still appear to run fine, even with the warnings.

My Rails environmentis 3.2.12, running on OSX 10.8.4.

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You must have upgraded to minitest 5.0. MiniTest::Unit::TestCase was renamed to Minitest::Test. Here are the [release notes](http://blog.zenspider.com/releases/2013/05/minitest-version-5-0-0-has-been-released.html).

Comment: okay, but any hints on how to get rid of the warnings, how to make things right for minitest 5?

Comment: Specify version 4.7.5 in your Gemfile: `gem "minitest", "4.7.5"`

Comment: But why can't I use minitest 5 if I want? Ah, are you saying that minitest 5 is not compatible with ActiveSupport for some reason?

Comment: Rails 4.0 an below use `MiniTest::Unit::TestCase`, which is what is deprecated in Minitest 5.0. If you want to not get the deprecated warning, use a version where that isn't deprecated. Rails 4.1 uses `Minitest::Test`, which was added in Minitest 5.0.

Answer (score 7):

Another possibility: you're using a newer version of ruby.  I was getting this warning/error running on ruby 2.1.2 (even with minitest 4.7.5); downgrading to ruby 2.0.0 resolved it

Comment: This is being called from [stdlib `Test::Unit::TestCase`](https://github.com/rubysl/rubysl-test-unit/blob/c24e9beb78656e9d40aa87598976e7bcdc7e7b6f/lib/test/unit/testcase.rb#L8) in Ruby 2.1. Downgrading to Minitest 4 or Ruby 2.0 seem to be the only solutions until stdlib updates for Minitest 5.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the new gem version of **test-unit** and **minitest** together. Example:

```
gem "test-unit", "~> 3.0"
gem "minitest", "~> 5.5"
```