# How can I get rid of these minitest errors/warnings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a rails 3.2.14 project, and I'm developing on a windows 7 machine.

I recently started getting these warnings when running `bundle exec rspec`:

```
MiniTest::Unit::TestCase is now Minitest::Test. From C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit/testcase.rb:8:in '<module:Unit>' 
MiniTest::Unit::TestCase is now Minitest::Test. From C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/test_case.rb:12:in '<module:ActiveSupport>'
MiniTest::Unit::TestCase is now Minitest::Test. From C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/descendants_tracker.rb:34:in 'inherited'
MiniTest::Unit::TestCase is now Minitest::Test. From C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/descendants_tracker.rb:34:in 'inherited'
MiniTest::Unit::TestCase is now Minitest::Test. From C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/descendants_tracker.rb:34:in 'inherited'
MiniTest::Unit::TestCase is now Minitest::Test. From C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/descendants_tracker.rb:34:in 'inherited'
Run options: include {:focus=>true}
```

Following the answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17461245/what-does-this-minitestunittestcase-warning-mean) (What does this MiniTest::Unit::TestCase warning mean?), I tried to downgrade to minitest 4.0 by adding this to my gemfile:

```
gem 'minitest', '~> 4'
```

Once I do that, however, I get these errors when testing is done:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/unit.rb:849:in `write': closed stream (IOError)
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/unit.rb:849:in `puts'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/unit.rb:849:in `puts'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/unit.rb:1069:in `_run'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/unit.rb:1059:in `run'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/unit.rb:795:in `block in autorun'
```

Figuring that it might be a problem with ruby, I upgraded to 1.9.3.p429, but no joy there, the behavior persists.  How can I fix these?