# MInitest Rails 4.1.0rc1 issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I loaded new rails onto my system and now when i runt the test i am getting the below exception. Please advise

```
~/railsprojects/my_blog (master) ∴ rake test
MiniTest::Unit::TestCase is now Minitest::Test. From /Users/pranavaswaroop/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit/testcase.rb:8:in `<module:Unit>'
rake aborted!
MiniTest v5.3.0 is out of date.
`gem install minitest` and add `gem 'minitest' to you test helper.
/Users/pranavaswaroop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/turn-0.9.6/lib/turn/minitest.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/pranavaswaroop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/turn-0.9.6/lib/turn.rb:13:in `require'
/Users/pranavaswaroop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/turn-0.9.6/lib/turn.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/pranavaswaroop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
/Users/pranavaswaroop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/Users/pranavaswaroop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
/Users/pranavaswaroop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
/Users/pranavaswaroop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
/Users/pranavaswaroop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
/Users/pranavaswaroop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler.rb:131:in `require'
/Users/pranavaswaroop/railsprojects/my_blog/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/pranavaswaroop/railsprojects/my_blog/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
~/railsprojects/my_blog (master) ∴
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this MiniTest::Unit::TestCase warning mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17461245/what-does-this-minitestunittestcase-warning-mean)

Answer (score 4):

I were using `turn` gem, problem solved by removing it.

Comment: I also ran into this problem. For reference, here are two related `turn` issues: https://github.com/turn-project/turn/issues/122 and https://github.com/turn-project/turn/issues/127. Sadly the `turn` project doesn't seem to be maintained at the moment, I'll look into [Tapout](https://github.com/rubyworks/tapout).